How to use a list view with dismissables inside a page view in Flutter?
I am trying to use a vertically scrolling list view with horizontally (right to left swiping) dismissable items on a page which is inside a horizontally scrolling page view. This page is the last in my page view and I need left to right swipes to navigate back in the page view, and right to left swipes to dismiss items in the list view.
I have tried wrapping my list view in a gesture detector in an attempt to capture the right to left swipes and call pageController.previousPage and leave the right to left swipes to the dismissable item in the list view. Unfortunately I think the dismissable items are catching all horizontal gestures regardless of direction as the gesture detector is not picking anything up. Does anyone know how to approach solving this problem? Thank you.
part of navigation controller build method:
body: ListView(
        children: [
             ...
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 730,
            child: PageView(
              controller: _pageController,
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              children: [
                const VisualisationPage(),
                ViewTasksPage(pageController: _pageController,), // the page with my list view
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),

part of ViewTasksPage build method:
return Scaffold(
        body: GestureDetector( // attempt at grabbing horizontal swipes
          onHorizontalDragEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
            print(
                "Swipe Detected: Velocity ${details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx}");
            if (details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx > 0) {
              print('Swipe right');
              if (widget.pageController.hasClients) {
                final currentPage = widget.pageController.page;
                if (currentPage != null && currentPage > 0) {
                  widget.pageController.previousPage(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                  );
                }
              }
            } else {
              print('Swipe left');
            }
          },
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    ...
                    return ListView.builder( // list of dismissable items
                      ...
                        return Dismissible(
                          key: Key(doc.id),
                          direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                          ...
                          onDismissed: (direction) async {
                          ...
                          },
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text(task['name'] ?? 'No name'),
                            subtitle: ...
                            onTap: () {
                             ...
                            },
                ...
      );

